# CMake cant find GMP library when compiling minetest

Tags: cmake, gmp

I'm attempting to compile Minetest on windows and CMake is complaining:

```
CMake Error at C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:846 (_find_package):
  By not providing "FindGMP.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "GMP", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GMP" with any of
  the following names:

    GMPConfig.cmake
    gmp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "GMP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "GMP_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "GMP" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:293 (find_package)
```

I dont understand CMake very well. What is CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH? Can I define CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in CMakeLists.txt?

I found several files online called GMPConfig.cmake can I just download them, put them in my project somewhere (probably in the gmp_x64-windows directory inside the vckpg projects directory?

What if I just install GMP on windows will that somehow update some kind of global path variable that will allow CMake to find the binary?

Comment: [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html). You can initialize it in the configure command using [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D) or [`list(APPEND)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#append). I'd recommend the former. You need to install GMP. If it comes with [a find-config script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-modes), then put the directory containing it in the prefix path.

Comment: Strange that you're getting problems, since purportedly, "_Bundled mini-GMP is used if not present_" ([source](https://github.com/minetest/minetest#dependencies)). Also GMP repo is here: https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip. From a cursory glance, I don't see any CMake files there. If you have GMP already installed, you could try to model what other projects like eigen do: https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/cmake/FindGMP.cmake. I don't know if CMake bundles a find-module script for GMP